# Convert Image to Uint8List in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to Convert Image to Uint8List in Flutter

I have Image it not from asset or file I want to convert Image to Uint8List

Comment: where does the data come from then? from the network via `http://` protocol? or it comes form other sources?

Comment: @pskink I generated myself from canvas and then converted to image with this code Image.memory(Uint8List bytes);  and i want to get back uint8List from Image

Comment: so if you pass `UInt8List` to `Image.memory` then what "other" `UInt8List` do you want to get?

Comment: @pskink Yes i dont access UInt8List i want get back from Image

Comment: sorry I have no idea what you really want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work.

```
final data = await image.toByteData();
final result = data.buffer.asUint8List();
```

Comment: it is not ui image

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this function successfully:

```
Future<Uint8List> convertImageProviderToUint8List(ImageProvider imageProvider) async {
  // Create an ImageStream.
  final ImageStream stream = imageProvider.resolve(ImageConfiguration.empty);

  // Completer to handle the asynchronous operation.
  final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();

  // Listen to the stream of images.
  ImageStreamListener? listener;
  listener = ImageStreamListener(
    (ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
      // Complete with the image when it's available.
      completer.complete(image.image);

      // Remove the listener once the image is received.
      if (listener != null) {
        stream.removeListener(listener);
      }
    },
    onError: (dynamic exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
      // Handle errors, e.g., by completing with an error.
      completer.completeError(exception, stackTrace);

      // Remove the listener on error as well.
      if (listener != null) {
        stream.removeListener(listener);
      }
    },
  );

  // Add the listener to the stream.
  stream.addListener(listener);

  // Await the image.
  final ui.Image image = await completer.future;

  // Convert the image to a byte array.
  final ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  final Uint8List uint8list = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

  return uint8list;
}
```

Must admit GPT wrote most of it, but I can validate it's working in production

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Image(...).uint8List
```

with [flutter_image_converter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_converter).